# white-space and some css support for Cobalt

Tags: html, css, cobalt

I've been using Cobalt recently and I am converting an UI to make it work on Cobalt.
One of my problem is that I'm using a specific class for overflow :

```
.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The problem is that it seems that the "white-space: nowrap;" is not supported by Cobalt.
But when I am looking at the Cobalt documentation (http://cobalt.foo/development/reference/supported-features.html) it says that all these css properties are supported.
Any idea why it doesn't work and how to fix that ?

Comment: You need to post the actual cobalt code, specifically the piece that calls that class. From a css standpoint I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: All my apologies. It was using @extend from scss, so according to your comment I changed all of these by the actual css and it works now ... Thanks

Comment: No problem glad you were able to figure it out before the downvote gods got here

Comment: Cobalt team here. As Kaz said, for the best results please post minimal, self-contained pages (HTML+CSS) that demonstrate an issue.

Comment: Julien, I encourage you to repost your comment as the answer to your own question, perhaps it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It was using @extend from scss, so according to your comment I changed all of these by the actual css and it works now ... Thanks